# Access string variable outside for loop in java?

Tags: for-loop, get, jtable

hi folks i want to access a string variable outside for loop, so that i can use it for further coding. Here i am trying to get the values from Jtable and store it in string, to create a database table. The Whole Code is here: http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=zVEWY

```
Coding :
int row = table.getRowCount();

int column = table.getColumnCount();

for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {

for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {

 //System.out.println(table.getValueAt(j, i));
  String readstr = (String) table.getValueAt(j, i);   // I WANT TO ACCESS THIS STRING


 }

 }


 try{
   // FILE READ AND TABLE CREATE
   String tname="example";
   String dbname="DB123";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn= (Connection)    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB123","root","");
    Statement stmt=(Statement) conn.createStatement();

    System.out.println("connect");



     DatabaseMetaData dmd = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
     while((readstr=brr.readLine())!=null)                     // TO USE IT HERE
    {
     ResultSet rs = dmd.getTables(null,"MigrationDB", "example", null);
     //set not null column
     if (String.valueOf(readstr).contains("NO"))
  readstr=readstr.replaceAll("NO", "not null");
     else if(String.valueOf(readstr).contains("YES"))
       readstr=readstr.replaceAll("YES", "");
     if(String.valueOf(readstr).contains("PRIMARY"))
         readstr=readstr.replaceFirst("PRIMARY","primary key");
    System.out.println("replace string "+readstr);
  int k=1;
   if (!rs.next())
  {
  stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE "+tname+ "("+readstr+")");

    }
 else{
     System.out.println(readstr);
     stmt.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE "+tname+ " ADD("+readstr+")");
      System.out.println("altered");

      }
     }

    }
     catch (Exception e){}

   }


    }
```

Thank You.

Comment: Just declare it outside the loop . BTW , I'm unable to understand what are you trying to achieve in that code ! What is `brr` ? And why should you use the same `readstr` variable below ?

Comment: @Noob UnChained hi, actually brr is wrong, i have changed it to: while(readstr!=null)
        {,  i am using readstr to get and store Jtable values in it then to use it to create database table, this way : stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE "+tname+ "("+readstr+")");

Comment: @Noob UnChained, i have posted the whole code here : http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=zVEWY

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what local variables are and what is their lifetime. I suggest reading through this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm

In you case, just declaring readstr outside the for loop would do what you want.

```
String readstr;
for(//loop condition) {
readstr = read value ;
}
```

Comment: hi, i did what you said, but i coundn't access it inside try{ , i have posted the whole code here : http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=zVEWY

Comment: You couldn't access it INSIDE the try block? what exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: In output it shows till connect after that it doesn't shows the values of String readstr  of forloop,   System.out.println("connect");
System.out.println(readstr);

Comment: Again, you haven't yet understood the block scope of a variable. Since readstr has been declared inside the try{} block, it belongs to the try block and can only be accessed inside that try block. If you want access it outside that block, simply declare it in a common higher level block (main, in your case).

Comment: hi , i am a beginner, can you check my whole code and help me out ?